# Does Struts 2 have any memory issues

Tags: struts2

I have a webapp developed with struts2 deployed in tomcat 5.5. The server has other applications deployed in it. But the app created with struts2 is very slow. Any ideas? How does Struts 2 handle object creation? And is there anything I can do on the tomecat server..

Answer (score 4):

How slow is it?  What are you doing?  are you sure it is Struts 2 that is slow and not your application code?  Did you do any profiling?  What were the results?

Check this out: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/performance-tuning.html

I found serving the static content from a folder increased the speed.

Answer (score 2):

Well few details are really required for some one to answer your question in more good way

1. Which Struts2 version you are using
2. At which place/part do you think application is slow

as per my experience there are certain areas where Struts2 have known problems, OGNL in itself sometime creates problem since this is the part of the framework which took most of the time, this has been known to fixed in 3.x version of OGNL so you can get new jar of OGNL and than can test your application.
Second use some profiler and it will help you to catch the culprit like any thread blocking etc.

Comment: I use Struts 2.2.0, almost every page loads slow.. I am using 3.x version of OGNL

Comment: which version of freemarker you are using try to upgrade freemarker jar also as in some cases multiple freemarker thread case also impact the performance,still my suggestion is simple try to use some profiling and check which thing is making the application working so slow, since if you are using persistence framework it can also lead to problem. currently we all can give you suggestion based on our experience but if you come up with profiling information some one in community will be able to hit the problem in right place

Comment: I Tried using netbeans profile but everytime I try to run the profiler its giving me filterStart error in the tomcat logs.. not sure why?

Comment: some how i have no idea about netbeans IDE and its profiler :(

Answer (score 1):

What OS is Tomcat running on?

If it's Linux, you may have run into a lack of entropy issue.
If this command returns something less than 200, it could explain your issue:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

If it is low (or watch during startup/making requests), try pointing /dev/random to /dev/urandom. (Not for secure Production, but to test in Dev should be fine):

```
mv /dev/random /dev/random.orig
ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

And try starting Tomcat again.

Comment: I am using Linux, the command you gave returns a value greater than 200.

Comment: May be similar to what I've run into myself. Even if greater than 200, may drop lower during a request or during Tomcat's startup. Try moving /dev/random to /dev/random_orig and creating a symbolic for /dev/random to /dev/urandom.

Comment: I finally found out how to use netbeans profiler, found out that the jar files included in the web-app are creating memory leak. Is there something that can be done for this?

Comment: What type of jar files can be moved to the tomcat lib?

Comment: If its your classes creating a memory leak, you should fix it. If it's Struts jars, you should report it to the Struts mailing list(s) or Bug tracking system.